# Which crypto currencies have their own stack exchange site?

Tags: community

I believe a coin has a solid community backing if they have their own stack exchange site. Which other crypto currencies aside from Bitcoin has their own stack exchange?

Comment: You can probably try one by one xxxxx.stackexchange.com to find that out.

Comment: Ethereum and ripple.

Comment: links to these sites?

Answer (score 3):

**Stack Exchange Sites for Cryptocurrencies:**

**Bitcoin**
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

**Ethereum**
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

**Monero**
https://monero.stackexchange.com/

**Other Proposals:**

**NEO-Blockchain**
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110921/neo-blockchain

**Augur**
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106367/augur

**Factom**
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/114019/factom

**Sia**
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/114211/sia

**Golem**
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109578/golem

These are the present list to the best of my knowledge.

Update:

An updated list can be found here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363121/where-can-i-ask-cryptocurrency-or-blockchain-questions/363122#363122

Comment: None of the "other proposals" made it to beta or out of beta unfortunately, in case anybody stumbles on this old answer. Other's did make it though.

Comment: We (the mod team on Cryptography) have created a list on [Cryptography Meta](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1510/which-crypt-currency-sites-are-there-on-stack-exchange-and-everywhere-else/1511#1511). Maybe we should keep an up-to-date list on the generic Meta as well...